# JSONPath can't query element

Tags: javascript, json, xpath, jsonpath

I've been trying to move some of my webapps configuration from an xml file to a redis store.

here is a snippet of my json.

```
{"project":
 {"host":"www.testtest1.com","skin":"S1","setup":
    {"project_name":"test project","status_available":
      {"bool":"1","link":"some link"}
    }
  }
}
```

what i want to do is get a match on host AND skin.  I was under the impression the way to do this is by querying.

```
$.project[?(@.host=="www.testtest1.com" && @.skin == "S1")
```

but on this site http://jsonpath.curiousconcept.com/ is keeps returning a false.

previously i was using Nokogiri to handle this along with XPATH. The way i made this same query with XPath was

```
xml.xpath("//project[@host='www.testtest1.com'][@skin='S1']
```

Is what i want to do possible with JSONPath?

Thanks

Comment: This has nothing to do with Ruby, so I've changed the tag to javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing wrong with your JSONPath. That JSONpath evaluator doesn't appear to work. If you were to use [this one](http://ashphy.com/JSONPathOnlineEvaluator/) with your JSONPath:

```
$.project[?(@.host == "www.testtest1.com" && @.skin=="S1")]
```

Then the expression works.

Comment: i can't believe it.  thank you for making me feel less insane!